# why my PyQt5 application is getting slow when qtableView data loaded

Tags: python, pyqt5

when i tried to load my sql data using qSqlQueryModel into qTableView in My Master Project,it taking too much time to load datas and application became slower. it also difficult to select rows and move scrollbar. firstly, i thought its due to unnecessary classes or functions which don't uses anywhere.
than i create a simple app where `connection.py` and `MainView.py` belongs. facing same issue with the new one.

i execute a simple query which will take 0.0001 sec to get results in SSMS ansonly 35 rows shown.
but in my project same query will take almost 8-10 seconds to display the datas in qTableView and became application slow. i didn't get any error message .
why it's happening? is there any wrong while using qSqlQueryModel or it's because of Indexing !!

[Note: view and connection must be separate file ]
[image]

**connection.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery,QSqlTableModel,QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys

SERVER = '*************,1433'
DATABASE = ''
USERNAME = '*******'
PASSWORD = '*******'

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
db.setDatabaseName(f'Driver={{SQL SERVER}}; Server={SERVER}; Database={DATABASE}; UID={USERNAME}; PWD={PASSWORD}')
db.open()
if db.open():
    print('connect to SQL Server successfully')
    
else:
    print('connection failed')
    

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   
    app.exit()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**mainView.py**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.displayData)


    def displayData(self):
        print('processing query...')
        input_value=self.lineEdit.text()
        sqlStatement = "select * from user.dbo.Accounts where accID ="+ input_value 
        print(sqlStatement)
        qry = QSqlQuery()
        qry.prepare(sqlStatement)
        qry.exec()
        
        model = QSqlQueryModel()
        model.setQuery(qry)
        self.tableView_1.setModel(model)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you have 2 accounts? If so, why do you use them for questions the same and identical questions? I'm going to report it.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes but i am not going to use my another account. this is my main account. i have created that by mistake and dont know how to remove it!

Comment: 1) I already report it so the moderator will analyze if you have abused the system, 2) I don't think the creation was an error since at least you have created 2 posts (one deleted and one still visible). 3) the help center clearly indicates how to delete an account (and it is very easy to find in google): https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: @eyllanesc i have deleted my account. sorry for my bad and violating the rule

Comment: @DhurjatiRiyan You can use [the contact us form](/contact) to request deletion of a profile, or to have them merged if that's a better option.

Comment: @JNat i have already deleted my account.

Comment: but i didn't get the answer for the above